# Android intent filter not working to launch activity from browser

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I've read a tutorial on how to launch an app from a link on the browser. I've created an activity 'TestLaunch'.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".TestMe"
        android:label="Test">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="testme.com" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Then I connected my android phone and clicked 'debug' on Eclipse. The app launched as usual. I openned the browser and typed 'testme.com'. The activity was not started as expected. Is this because the app is not fully installed on the phone or because I am understanding wrongly how the intent filter works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".TestMe"
    android:label="Test">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:host="www.testme.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: No, that just openned www.testme.com .

Comment: If you go to http://www.testme.com it should open up a selection dialog where you can choose which program you want to use to open the page, either Browser or your app...

Comment: It didn't work at first, but with little modifications. Also, it only did work using a <a href="mylink">click me</a> in a page - not by typing it directly to the browser.